# Why should I switch from developing in force.com platform to Salesforce DX?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Absolutely noob in regards to Salesforce and the development.
I followed some tutorials and built some stuff on my playground instance. I modelled some data, did some Apex Triggers and have done some workflow rules. Everything works so far.

Yet I am unsure why I should now switch to the Salesforce DX development process going for VS Code and doing my stuff there as I am pretty confident in what I have achieved so far without ever touching an IDE.

Is there somewhere a good summary of options and capabilities in regards to force.com "development" and/or SF DX development?

Best and stay healthy!

Answer (score 0):

Far and away the most important facet of shifting from in-org development to using Visual Studio Code and Salesforce DX is that your code and metadata can be stored in source control: versioned, replicated, reviewed, and managed through a software development process like any other technology stack.

Moving into version control enables you to go further in adopting development and deployment best practices:

- Use of packaging, if desired.
- Use of continuous integration for automated testing.
- Use of multiple environments, including particularly scratch orgs, for development before deploying into a persistent org.
- Use of available tools like the Apex debugger, code completion, SFDX plugins, and static analysis through third-party tools like PMD.

It's fine to complete declarative customization, in particular, inside an org, but that org should preferably be an ephemeral one - a scratch org or a refreshable sandbox - with work done captured to source control as the source of truth.